# ASP .NET - Validation Summary does not list down the error messages on a page

Tags: .net, asp.net

Problem:

Validation Summary does not list down the error messages on a page.  I have used Validation groups to distinguish the groups but still it doesn't work.  Also the function Page_ClientValidate returns false even though there are no controls invalid in the page.

Answer (score 0):

When using ValidationSummary use ValidationGroup attribute and assign this to all your validation controls and the action button:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="val" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="val" />

<asp:Button ValidationGroup="val" />
```